# xamarin how to change the unique id of child in firebase

Tags: c#, firebase, xamarin, firebase-realtime-database

I'm a beginner in firebase and i'm using nuget FirebaseDatabase.net.

I'm trying to replace the unique id of child with the users uid this is how it looks in the database

[image]

i tryed this code but it didnt work

```
private async void signupbutton_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // the registration part
    FirebaseClient firebaseClient = new FirebaseClient("foo");
    try
    {
        var authProvider = new FirebaseAuthProvider(new FirebaseConfig(webApiKey));
        var auth =  await authProvider.CreateUserWithEmailAndPasswordAsync(UserNewEmail.Text, UserNewPassword.Text);
        string getToken = auth.FirebaseToken;

      //save user info in database   

      await firebaseClient.Child("users").Child("some uid").PostAsync(new userinfo
        {

            firstName = UserFirstName.Text ,
            secondName = UsersecondName.Text
        }) ;

        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", auth.User.LocalId, "Ok");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await App.Current.MainPage.DisplayAlert("Alert", "ala " + ex.Message, "OK");
    }     
}
```

and this is the opject im trying to send

```
class userinfo
{
    public string firstName { get; set; }
    public string secondName { get; set; }
}
```

pleace let me know if my question needs  more Clarificatio thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

When you `Post` to Firebase Realtime Database it always creates a new child node with a generated unique ID. If you want to specify your own ID, specify the entire path you want to write to (including that ID) and then use `Put`.

```
                                                     //               
 await firebaseClient.Child("users").Child("some uid").child(getToken).PutAsync(new userinfo
{

    firstName = UserFirstName.Text ,
    secondName = UsersecondName.Text
}) ;
```